# why was one strike by a 10 year old girl effective?

Tags: streetfight

On our way come from school, a boy at least 6 yrs older grabbed both my friend's wrists & his 2 friends were closing fast.  Feeling that grappling @ his hands would be ineffective, I stepped behind him & sought the spot on his spine that was on a line with his mid-scapulae & hit him with my ulnar-side fist.  Not knowing why I had wanted that 1 spot, I was extremely surprised when he huffed out air, released my friend, & slowly sank to his knees. While his 2 wingmen stopped to check on the bully, my friend & I got away.  What the is that spot? Why did that work?

---

**Backstory:** I was 10 & had no training; no one I knew had training. As an adult, I became a registered occupational therapist with a emphasis on hand & upper extremity rehab. As a kid, the weird bit for me was the calm & wider perceptual field: "knowing" how much time I had before his 2 friends arrived; that it would be risky to try to release his hands; that to "find the spot" I had to search for "the line" running across his spine to reveal my target, and the certainty. It WAS as if I knew what I was doing, but I was only going on instinct. As an adult, I later understood that there are powerful centers on the body that can be used for wide effects, but this was never explained. The boy was fine but I got in trouble. Was wearing an  identifiable catholic school pinafore, was reported & the nuns did not want to hear my opinion it was justifiable,that my friend was scared & I was not willing to find out what 3 bullies might do. Whatever meta-mind place the info came from, I was grateful, but remain curious about the whole experience & that spot. Thanks for any opinions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where on the body you are referring too exactly.  But strikes to the spine are very effective and dangerous.

At age 10 it doesn't make a huge difference if you are male or female so far as muscle strength is concerned environmental factors (how the child spends their time, what they eat etc) will make more of a  difference.

If the boy was older than you you would probably also have been striking upwards to hit the target which exacerbates the damage caused by blows the torso.